# Proguard obfuscation and generic methods

Tags: java, android, generics, obfuscation, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate an Android App with ProGuard.

Here I have a class

```
public class Book implements DBbinded
```

And a generic method

```
private void storeDBObjects(ArrayList<? extends DBbinded> dbObjects)
```

The call of this method throws an java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap after obfuscation. What should I write into proguard.properties to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

I have just come across this problem and resolved it by specifying the 'Signature' attribute under the `-keepattributes` ProGuard argument.

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Signature,*Annotation*
```

I do not believe it is a ProGuard bug. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yep, signature is in the args!

Comment: In addition to the line stated above, I had to add a `keepclassmembers class <full qualified class name>` to get rid of the exception

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in ProGuard. You should check if installing [the latest version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/) helps (ProGuard 4.9 beta1 at this time: copy proguard4.9beta1/lib/proguard.jar in android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib). Otherwise, you can report the problem on [ProGuard's bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=54750&atid=474704).